# Hibernate: Don't query inheriting subclass with Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

Say I have a class with a subclass:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class ClassA {
    // columns

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TABLE_B")
    public static class ClassB extends ClassA {
        // extra columns
    }
}
```

When I want to query TABLE_A I try `session.createCriteria(ClassA.class)`, but it ends up giving me results from *both* TABLE_A and TABLE_B. How can I make it only get results from TABLE_A (i.e. the parent class only)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `type` function :

```
select a from ClassA a where type(a) not in (ClassB)
```